# Looking for pure Java 3D library

Tags: java, 3d

I have a very simple scenario: given are bare 3d points and I need to connect all these points and draw a surface. And for this case I need a very basic and really pure Java library without any dependencies.

Do you know such a library?

Comment: The Java mindset is to tend to do a lot of research into existing libraries first, find the best one, then use the minimum of code to integrate it. So these questions are less off-topic than say the equivalent in a language with a more do-it-yourself mindset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Java Surface Plot might be what you're looking for.

http://javasurfaceplot.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Amazing. If I would want to create something like this by myself, what are the keywords to google for and get rich of?

Comment: I just looked at your post and used java surface plot, sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes to see the obvious! Had it happen to myself many times.

Comment: I can also suggest Orson Charts it is a 3D chart library by the author of JFreeChart (me).  It has no additional dependencies because the 3D rendering is done in software using standard Java2D graphics:  http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/

Answer (score 1):

Do you know (or test) Java 3D API ?

Useful link : [Java 3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html) or [Java net link](http://java3d.java.net/)

There is also another library : [jmathplot](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php?id=jmathplot%3atutorial) (to draw diagram or others) --> it's easier than java 3d API.

It's two diferent philosophy. With the first you have to "draw point by point", with the second (jmathplot) you can use predefined elements and mathematical functions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with the hardware just about any Java 3d library is going to have some dependencies.

You might try this:

http://www.mediafire.com/download/8ui3uwduw17bnx9/OpenGL.rar

There is a video tutorial set available for it. Just drawing a surface shouldn't be a problem.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1EvbHFtjCE

If you really want to get into Java 3D I would just search around for as much info on the various competing libraries and pick one for what you want to do with it.

edit:

The surface library fron other answer looks promising. I also found https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/ the JOGL or The Java API for OpenGL.